# OnChange event not firing, function is not out of scope

Tags: jquery, onchange

```
function language(value)
{
    window.alert(value);
}

<select onchange="language(this.val())">
    <option value="Português">Português</option>
    <option value="Inglês">Inglês</option>
</select>
```

Why is this not working?

The problem is not the function out of scope, I have used this code to test that it's not:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   language("testing");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so `this.val()` is not a valid function `.val()` is a jQuery element function you need `$(this).val()` in your `onchange` attribute.

```
<select onchange="language($(this).val())">
    <option value="Português">Português</option>
    <option value="Inglês">Inglês</option>
</select>
```

or use `this.value` like so,

```
<select onchange="language(this.value)">
    <option value="Português">Português</option>
    <option value="Inglês">Inglês</option>
</select>
```

If that does not fix the issue, you should use something like the Chrome developer tools or FireBug to catch the exception that is thrown when you change the select. That will give you a very good idea of where to look for the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just stick to just jQuery and do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select').change(function () {
        alert(this.value);
    });
});
```

And in case you want to use the javascript only, do this:

```
<select onchange="language(this.value)">   <!-- Not this.val() -->
    <option value="Português">Português</option>
    <option value="Inglês">Inglês</option>
</select>
```

For testing, you can change the `onchange` event to `onchange="alert(this.value)"`